# How to setup correct cURL request for X Post?

Tags: php, api, curl

I have an API to track the shipment, the API request is below and worked well as excepted,

```
 curl -X POST 
     --header '17token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     --header 'Content-Type:application/json'
     --data '[{"number":"RR123456789CN"}]'
     https://api.17track.net/track/v1/register
```

Here is my cURL code to get the response.

```
<?php

// started curl
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.17track.net/track/v1/register",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "number:RR123456789CN", // SOMETHING IS WRONG HERE.

    //data '[{"number":"RR123456789CN"}]'

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
         "17token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "header 'Content-Type:application/json"
        ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

The above code is showing error.

`{"code":0,"data":{"errors":[{"code":-18010013,"message":"Submitted data is invalid."}]}}`

I have tried all kinds of data structures like :

```
 1. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "RR123456789CN", 

 2. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[{number:RR123456789CN}]",
  
 3. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{number:RR123456789CN}",   
          
 4. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{number:RR123456789CN}',   
                
 5. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{number:RR123456789CN}',    
                    
 6. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "data '[{number:RR123456789CN}]'",

 7. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"number\": \"RR123456789CN\"}",

 8. CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[{\"number\": \"RR123456789CN\"}]",
```

but all the above data structures are failing and showing the same error.

1. I think I am doing something wrong with X POST / POST or
2. I am failing to request properly.

> Edit

**After doing some research I have written new code..**

```
<?php

// setting the main url
$url = 'https://api.17track.net/track/v1/register';

// the tracking id as array
$post_data = array (
'number' => 'RR123456789CN',);

// start
$ch = curl_init();

// URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Returntransfer = true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Post = true
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Header # 1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "17token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

// Header # 2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'Content-Type:application/json');

// posting tracking id
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

// Getting data in a string ($output)
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// error msg if fails
if ($output === FALSE){

    echo "cURL Error:" . curl_error($ch);
}

// turning off the cURL
curl_close($ch);

// Printing the output.
print_r($output);
?>
```

Now i am getting `{"code":401,"data":{"errors":[{"code":-18010002,"message":"Access token is invalid."}]}}` error.

**Note : Token is valid and correct, i think something is wrong with my code.**

Thank you.

Comment: Is your curl on the command line have excepted response?

Comment: yes sir. the api will send tracking details as json.

Comment: Does https://reqbin.com/req/php/c-kvv2ga1h/convert-curl-to-php help?

Comment: i have voted to close this question as "Needs debugging details" - specifically, it needs the api documentation, to tell us how your request is actually supposed to look, rather than what you've tried.

Comment: OMG!! @NicoHaase , Thank your for the link. I was completely unaware about anything like "Curl Commands to PHP Code Converter". Thank you for the amazing tool and a site link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send your data as **raw** body:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array(0 => array("number" => "CM436202796IN"));
$data = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.17track.net/track/v1/register',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data, // Mistake is here
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    '17token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: i suggest using json_encode instead, it ensures proper json encoding of variables, eg proper escaping of `"` if the number ever contains a `"`, it also makes the code more maintainable imo, 
```CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
                0 => array(
                    "number" => "CM436202796IN"
                )
            )),
```

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes, it's a better way. I edit my answer with.

Comment: you should *NOT* be using CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST here. quote documentation: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html : ```Many people have wrongly used this option to replace the entire request with their own, including multiple headers and POST contents. While that might work in many cases, it will cause libcurl to send invalid requests and it could possibly confuse the remote server badly. Use CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to set POST data.``` - use CURLOPT_POST instead.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of people use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST wrong, it is a very common error ^^

Comment: I'm that lot of people. when writing plain PHP code :) but after this, I will change my codes.

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
```

with just

```
CURLOPT_POST=>1
```

and replace

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "number:RR123456789CN", // SOMETHING IS WRONG HERE.
```

with

```
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
                0 => array(
                    "number" => "CM436202796IN"
                )
            )),
```

and replace

```
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
         "17token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "header 'Content-Type:application/json"
        ],
```

with

```
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
         "17token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "Content-Type: application/json"
        ],
```

Comment: Thank you @hanshenrik for the improvement.